# Getting errors when retrieving the list of MIBs from a snmp daemon

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd, mib

I'm trying to configure and use the SLES 11 (OpenSUSE) snmp daemon.

The first thing I want to do is to run the snmpd daemon and query the availables MIBs. I do this by executing the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/snmpd start
sudo snmpwalk -mALL -v1 -ccomname localhost system 2 > /dev/null
```

After executing it, I obtain the following errors:

```
Expected "(" (_): At line 254 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/acs4000.mib
Bad operator ((): At line 254 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/acs4000.mib
Should be ACCESS (_): At line 134 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NFS-220.mib
Bad parse of OBJECT-TYPE: At line 134 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NFS-220.mib
Timeout: No Response from localhost
```

I have not installed any MIB, so the displayed above must be the OS default ones.

I do not know why the error is occurring nor how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by replacing the "_" characters that produced the error by "-" characters.